# Update a table that is a subset of another table based on a time frame

Tags: sql-server

This is my first post on stack overflow and the first time I have not been able to find an answer. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. I am grabbing data from a data warehouse I only have read access to. I then create my own table using a subset of the data in the original table. Specifically, I am looking for fire calls that occurred in the rolling last x hours. I do this by dropping and creating the table using a SQL Server Agent Job, this can't be right but it works fine. I really want to know the best practice for this. I looked at Update, Merge, and many other similar ways to do this here, but none were based on a time-frame like I need. I can't think of a good way to insert new rows that do not exist and delete rows that are older than x hours. We generate a text file off of this table every 2 minutes that is loaded into a third party reporting system. Units can then select their call and have all the data in this table loaded into their form. We want them to only have to look at 20 hours of calls, but this may need to increase or decrease. I am not sure what will happen if the text file creator hits the table the exact moment it is being deleted and before it is recreated.

Here is my current SQL:

```
DROP TABLE CAD.dbo.EMEDS_FCARSCALLUNIT

SELECT 
    FCARSCallUnit.CALLKEY, FCARSCallUnit.UNITKEY, 
    FCARSCallUnit.UNIT_ID, FCARSCallUnit.CALL_NO, 
    FCARSCallUnit.UNIT_DISPATCH_DATE,
    FCARSCallUnit.UNIT_DISPATCH_TIME, FCARSCallUnit.UNIT_ENROUTE_DATE, 
    FCARSCallUnit.UNIT_ENROUTE_TIME, FCARSCallUnit.UNIT_ONSCENE_DATE, 
    FCARSCallUnit.UNIT_ONSCENE_TIME, FCARSCallUnit.UNIT_ATPATIENT_DATE, 
    FCARSCallUnit.UNIT_ATPATIENT_TIME, FCARSCallUnit.UNIT_BEG_TRAN_DATE, 
    FCARSCallUnit.UNIT_BEG_TRAN_TIME, FCARSCallUnit.UNIT_END_TRAN_DATE, 
    FCARSCallUnit.UNIT_END_TRAN_TIME, 
    FCARSCallUnit.UNIT_BEG_LAST_TRAN_DATE, 
    FCARSCallUnit.UNIT_BEG_LAST_TRAN_TIME, 
    FCARSCallUnit.UNIT_END_LAST_TRAN_DATE, 
    FCARSCallUnit.UNIT_END_LAST_TRAN_TIME, FCARSCallUnit.UNIT_TRANS_COUNT, 
    FCARSCallUnit.UNIT_PREEMPT_DATE, FCARSCallUnit.UNIT_PREEMPT_TIME, 
    FCARSCallUnit.UNIT_CLEAR_DATE, FCARSCallUnit.UNIT_CLEAR_TIME, 
    FCARSCallUnit.UNIT_HOSPITAL_DATE, FCARSCallUnit.UNIT_HOSPITAL_TIME, 
    FCARSCallUnit.UNIT_AT_PATIENT_DATE, FCARSCallUnit.UNIT_AT_PATIENT_TIME
INTO 
    CAD.dbo.EMEDS_FCARSCALLUNIT
FROM 
    [DWLIVE].[dbo].[FCarsCallUnit]
WHERE   
    [UNIT_DISPATCH_DATE] >= CAST(dateadd (hh, -20, getdate()) AS datetime)
```

Comment: Why drop and recreate your subset table when you can truncate it?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am not sure how I would use truncate to keep a rolling x hours of data.

Comment: You could just replace your drop table statement with this: `TRUNCATE TABLE CAD.dbo.EMEDS_FCARSCALLUNIT`. To me it sounds like, you are trying to clear all your data from your subset table and store only data from a single run?

Comment: Nice edit.  If comments raise interesting / relevant points, its always good to add the information to your question :)  Makes it a pleasure for people to answer...(Otherwise many would just ignore the question)

Comment: Thanks for the original edit to my post. Select into does not work when using truncate. I assume i will then need to use insert or maybe merge.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  To answer 'what is best practice' is impossible without knowing your actual requirements.  If you want to collect data from a time frame, your query is fine.  Perhaps you want to append to your table, rather than dropping it all the time.  If you keep dropping your table, you will also drop your indexes etc, which should be replaced (if you are using indexes, which you will want to on a larger table).
I would suggest using `INSERT INTO .. VALUES...` structure for this.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776381%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

The format exemplified in the link, I would use for this is:

```
INSERT INTO YourTable (LocationID, CostRate, ModifiedDate)
    SELECT LocationID, CostRate, GETDATE() FROM Production.Location
    WHERE CostRate > 0;
```

Start with just a few columns until you get it working, then add all your columns that you need

And as mentioned in comments, you can empty the table using TRUNCATE...This will keep your indexes...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can't think of a good way to insert new rows that do not exist and delete rows that are older than x hours. We generate a text file off of this table every 2 minutes that is loaded into a third party reporting system. Units can then select their call and have all the data in this table loaded into their form. We want them to only have to look at 20 hours of calls, but this may need to increase or decrease. I am not sure what will happen if the text file creator hits the table the exact moment it is being deleted and before it is recreated.

Comment: I think maybe insert with NOT EXISTS may work, but I have not been able to get it to work.

Comment: This detail, should be added to your question.  You can add it now :)  ... If you use TRANSACTIONS in SQL Server, then SQL Server will take care of this for you...  The way your text file is generated is the key, if it is written properly it will wait until SQL is ready to pass data to it...Ideally, once a text file is created it should flag every row in the SQL table so that you know those rows are ready for deletion. Then you should only delete at the exact moment after the text extract is taken

Comment: I would separate this into 2 steps.... Purge data (delete) only AFTER your text extract has run, perhaps add this to the same 'script' that does the text extract.  Then run your inserts separately...Using NOT EXISTS will work, but will not perform very well (Well, you can improve the performance but you will need well tuned indexes)

Comment: Also, everything will run better if you add indexes to your table (that you extract from into text).  Another good reason not to DROP the table..Simply truncate the data - even all the data at once is fine.

Comment: Take baby steps ... Get your Insert working without SELECT .. INTO and without Dropping your table. Then play with your NOT EXISTS... I would probably use a JOIN instead of NOT EXISTS ... It helps if you show us what you tried (in your Question...)...  When you find it is all too slow, then you can add indexes

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try your suggestions. I think truncating may be the answer. I have no good way of determining new data that is different from existing data, other then it's there at the next select. Callkey is incremental and is the PK, so I may be able to compare that to last record? Deleting records with a dispatch_time > 20 hours ago is easy. I will let you know how it works out.